# Problem with decoding token - jwtHelper - ANgularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with jwtHelper.

After coding the data, I want to decode using:

```
myServices.service('checkToken', function( store, jwtHelper){

    this.payload = function(){

        var token = store.get ('token');
        token = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);

        return token;
    }

});
```

However, the console receives such an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.decodeToken (angular-jwt.js:233)
    at Object.payload (services.js:11)
```

Line 11: `token = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the store is returning the token? Also I see a space between get and the paranthesis.

Comment: Right now I noticed that he is getting 'undefined'. However, when I click on the submit form, it receives this token.

Do you have an idea where the error is?

Comment: Did you remove the space between get and the paranthesis? Is token defined between store get and decodeToken?

Comment: Yes, delete remove space.

Comment: You could try returning the decodeToken result instead of first setting it in the variable token.

Comment: In the PHP API, I see that after clicking the code generates.

However, this store is not intercepted.